# Cannot a select query fields in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

The following is the query that I have entered in the Report Builder Dataset. However, I can only see the variables for first Select * from #Temp and not the variables from the second select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Reporting Services only ever expects and can only handle one resultset to populate a DataSet - it will accept the first resultset returned by your query and discard anything else.

Some options I can think of:

1. use two DataSets for the separate queries.
2. Use one detail DataSet and apply any required aggregation at the report level.
3. Use a `UNION ALL` or similar to coalesce the two resultsets at the query level.

Comment: yeah but 1 query is just pulling the results the second is the aggregation. Is it possible that I can create inital dataset and use that to create the second dataset....?

Comment: You have two `SELECT` statements returning data; SSRS can only consider the first. If you want to have both the detail and summary data as DataSets, you must have separate DataSets. You cannot use one DataSet as the Data Source for another DataSet. If you only want summary data remove the `Select * from #Temp;` statement.

Comment: No I need both....and if i create two datasets then There will be lots of useless steps....in there

Comment: Sorry, to go back to the original question it's one query per DataSet - that's just SSRS functionality. I have presented some alternatives; apologies if none of them are suitable.